# Data template not found for item in web database

Tags: azure-search

Found the below error in log while indexing sitecore azure indexes.Once we get this error indexing gets stuck and there will be multiple errors in log and none of the items get indexed.

> ERROR Data template '{DD22F1B3-BD87-4DB2-9E7D-F7A496888D43}' not found for item '/sitecore/system/Modules/PowerShell/Script Library/SXA/SXA - Upgrade/Functions/Cmdlets/Scripts/Get-PendingUpgradeScripts' in 'web' database

Comment: did you publish all items under : /sitecore/system/Modules/PowerShell and their templates ?

Comment: @VladIobagiu The  /sitecore/system/Modules folder was missing. After adding that folder and publishing it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this issue fixed with the help of sitecore support and wanted to post it here so that it can be useful to other.

During Analysis i found that the missing template in web database was present in the master database but it was a orphan item (Modules folder was missing in templates) so when i published the templates the item didn't get published.

Then i found out that this issue is related to bug #10813 in Web Deploy package for Sitecore Powershell Extension 4.6 and 4.7 version.This issue was already resolved in web deploy package for Sitecore powershell Extension 4.7.2

The cause of this issue is the fact that there is no /sitecore/templates/Modules folder which contains the templates for PSE in your solution and as a result, all items based on these templates have the wrong path to their templates.
(for example /PowerShell Console/PowerShell Script Library instead of /sitecore/templates/Modules/PowerShell Console/PowerShell Script Library)
In order to resolve this issue please perform the following steps:

1. Backup your master DB.
2. Perform the below code for master DB in order to create the missing folder (item).
3. Clear the cache using http://HOSTNAME/sitecore/admin/Cache.aspx.
4. Republish the site to the web.
5. Rebuild the indexes.

SQL Script:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Items] (ID, Name, TemplateID, MasterID, ParentID, Created, Updated)
    VALUES ('{E6904C9A-3ACE-4B53-B465-4C05C6B1F1CC}', 'Modules', '{239F9CF4-E5A0-44E0-B342-0F32CD4C6D8B}', '{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}', '{3C1715FE-6A13-4FCF-845F-DE308BA9741D}', GETUTCDATE(), GETUTCDATE());

INSERT INTO [dbo].[VersionedFields] (ItemId, FieldId, Language, Version, Value, Created, Updated)
    VALUES ('{E6904C9A-3ACE-4B53-B465-4C05C6B1F1CC}', '{D9CF14B1-FA16-4BA6-9288-E8A174D4D522}', 'en', '1', '20180123T172226Z', GETUTCDATE(), GETUTCDATE());
INSERT INTO [dbo].[VersionedFields] (ItemId, FieldId, Language, Version, Value, Created, Updated)
    VALUES ('{E6904C9A-3ACE-4B53-B465-4C05C6B1F1CC}', '{25BED78C-4957-4165-998A-CA1B52F67497}', 'en', '1', '20180123T172226Z', GETUTCDATE(), GETUTCDATE());
INSERT INTO [dbo].[VersionedFields] (ItemId, FieldId, Language, Version, Value, Created, Updated)
    VALUES ('{E6904C9A-3ACE-4B53-B465-4C05C6B1F1CC}', '{BADD9CF9-53E0-4D0C-BCC0-2D784C282F6A}', 'en', '1', 'sitecore\admin', GETUTCDATE(), GETUTCDATE());

INSERT INTO [dbo].[VersionedFields] (ItemId, FieldId, Language, Version, Value, Created, Updated)
    VALUES ('{E6904C9A-3ACE-4B53-B465-4C05C6B1F1CC}', '{8CDC337E-A112-42FB-BBB4-4143751E123F}', 'en', '1', '47d6c7a0-f99a-4c5a-8ff1-153af2e12acb', GETUTCDATE(), GETUTCDATE());

GO
```

After performing the above steps the issue got resolved.